# how to find a particular node exists in `'HTMLParagraphElement'` type of Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
this                 
<p>​adfad​</p>​                          // value in 'this'

this.toString()
"[object HTMLParagraphElement]"       // of type HTMLParagraphElement

this.outerHTML.indexOf('img')         // to find 'img' tag is there
-1
```

how to find a particular node exists in `'HTMLParagraphElement'` type of Object ?
 is there any better way of doing this apart from above mentioned way ?

Comment: Can you provide example of html that you say?

Comment: "<p>adfadfadf</p><p>adfasdf</p><p><br></p><p>adfasdf</p><img />"

Comment: Please don't post your code in comments, it's unreadable to all practical purposes (especially in the case of longer, more involved, code). [Edit] your question to include the code there, where people can more easily see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the length of the array `element.find(selector)` is 0, `element.find(selector).length == 0` where selector can be any jquery selector.

```js
console.log($('p').find('img').length);
console.log($('p').find('br').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>adfadfadf</p>
<p>adfasdf</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>adfasdf</p>
<img />
```